# Why span is not taking auto width in tailwind css?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a hover message within a span. For example, when we hover over the first span (parent span) its child span is shown. That's working fine but the child span is not taking auto width. Here is the code I have tried

```
<span class="group/item relative ml-2 h-6 w-6 bg-yellow-300">
Hover me
<span class="absolute top-7 right-auto z-10 hidden w-auto rounded-md bg-gray-900 px-3 py-1 text-[10px] text-white group-hover/item:block"> Create payment </span>
</span>
```

This code gives this result

[image]

I want this result

[image]

Please note that I want to get this result with `w-auto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `whitespace-nowrap` class on you children `span` which will prevent text from breaking after white spaces. Your span is taking width auto as expected it's just that default behavior of text is to break itself after a white space if there is no width left

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<span class="group/item relative ml-2 h-6 w-6 bg-yellow-300">
Hover me
<span class="absolute top-7 right-auto z-10 hidden w-auto rounded-md bg-gray-900 px-3 py-1 text-[10px] text-white group-hover/item:block whitespace-nowrap"> Create payment </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your valuable answer. Can you please help me with one another thing? I also want to know how do i center the child span? I want to center this automaticlly based on the parent span position

Comment: By center, do you mean to center it horizontally based on parent element?

Comment: Yes that's correct . that exactly what i want

Comment: remove "right-auto" class and add "left-[50%] translate-x-[-50%]" on you classes.